# Is there a way to bind data grid view with flat file data source?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In C# windows forms application I am looking for a way to bind a grid data view to a flat file that contain simple data to display as I dont want to use a complete database like SQL Server. I need to do add/delete/edit of these data from the grid, how I can do that ?

Please if you have a link to documentation or tutorial give it to me.

Comment: You can't simply bind file do data grid. You'll have to read the file to some sort of collection, bind it to data grid and then save your collection back to file when you change the row. Serialization might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's example how to do it:

```
private const string TestDataFilePath = @"C:\test\TestData.xml";
private readonly XmlSerializer _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataModel[]));
private DataModel[] Items { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Load += LoadData;
    btnSave.Click += SaveData;
}

private void SaveData( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    using (var file = File.Create(TestDataFilePath))
    {
        _serializer.Serialize(file, Items);
    }
}

private void LoadData( object sender, EventArgs eventArgs )
{
    using ( var file = File.Open( TestDataFilePath, FileMode.Open ))
    {
        Items = (DataModel[])_serializer.Deserialize( file );
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = Items;
}
```